# S3 Select on CSV file - how to match substring

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I have a CSV file uploaded to an S3 bucket. I want to return rows that match a substring of a field `Display`. What's the right SELECT syntax?

This returns 0 rows:

`"select * from s3object s where 'substring' in s.Display LIMIT 100"`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer:

`"select * from s3object s where s.Display LIKE '%substring%' LIMIT 100"`

More info... S3 Select uses [Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html) which uses [Presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/) as it's query engine.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that `"SELECT * FROM s3object s WHERE 'substring' IN s.Display` would only work if `s.Display` was an `ARRAY`.